# Is there a way to replace Jetty with Netty in Spring?

Tags: spring, netty, spring-websocket

I am looking for a replacement for Jetty in my Spring 4 application. Netty seem to be a good candidate. Is it possible to add support for Netty server (I am primarily interested in STOMP-over-websocket side) without hacking the Spring library, but via some configuration of it?